# @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) in Rest-Call not working when supplied time zone same as time zone of the server

Tags: java, rest, datetime-format

I have a Spring Boot Rest call which looks like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/bar", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Page<Bar>> getBarList(
        @RequestParam(name = "date", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime date)
```

The time zone of the server is +01:00[Europe/Berlin]. If I supply on the client-side a date that matches the time zone of the server, the call is reject as a bad request:

var date = "2019-01-01T00:01:00.000+01:00";

I can supply any other time zone and then the client side call successfully invokes the server-side function, e.g.:

```
2019-01-01T00:01:00.000-01:00
2019-01-01T00:01:00.000-07:00
2020-01-31T00:01:00.000Z
```

In fact any positive time zone results in a bad request error (e.g. also 2019-01-01T00:01:00.000+02:00 or 2019-01-01T00:01:00.000+03:00). How am I supposed to supply the time zone +1?

I believe I'm missing something how this works.

Comment: Try `OffsetDateTime` instead of `ZonedDateTime` because the formatting examples don't have a zone, they all just have an offset. Could work, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Good idea, thanks deHaar. Just tried it with OffsetDateTime instead of ZonedDateTime and it failed again as soon as the time zone is positive, e.g. contains a "+" and not "-".

Comment: Hmm... Not good ;-) Have you put a pattern for parsing or are you just relying on the `ISO.DATE_TIME`?

Comment: Found it: Have to replace + with %2B. I was silly ... ;-)

Comment: Oh, an encoding problem... As long as it works, good...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` symbol needs to be encoded, replace `+` sign with `%2B` this will resolve the issue

Comment: Do give more explanation to the answer. It doesn't look sufficient.

Comment: How can you encode the `+` pragmatically using Spring boots annotations?

i.e. `@RequestParam(value = "theDate", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) OffsetDateTime theDate,`

This is fails when we get a date like `2022-04-03T23:30:30.969+01:00`